# Why am I having issues using a struct in an abstract class?

Tags: c++, struct, abstract-class

I've created a simple example (since my classes are rather large). I've managed to reproduce the exact issue with the following code:

*Shape.h*

```
struct A {
    int Aa = 1;
    int Ab;
    int Ac;
};

struct B {
    int Ba = 10;
    int Bb;
    int Bc;
};

class Shape {
public:
    virtual int type() = 0;
    virtual int bonus() = 0;
    A aStruct;
    B bStruct;
};
```

This is the abstract class. I kept it simple on purpose.

*Circle.h*

```
#include "Shape.h"

class Circle : public Shape {
private: //for some reason, names of variables MUST differ from the name of the function 
    int type1 = 0;
    int bonus1 = 1000;
public:
    Circle() {}
    Circle(int);

    int type() { return type1; }
    int bonus() { return bonus1; }

    A aStruct;
    B bStruct;
};
```

*Circle.cpp*

```
#include "Circle.h"

Circle::Circle(int s) {
    type1 = s;
    aStruct.Ab = 666;
    aStruct.Ac = 777;
    bStruct.Bb = 888;
    bStruct.Bc = 999;
}
```

This all compiles together happily. Please excuse the nonsensical values/logic, they're just that - nonsensical.

Here is the main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Circle.h"
using namespace std;

void abstractFuncCheck(Shape& s) {
    cout << s.aStruct.Ab; //does not work
}

int main() {
    Circle c = 140;
    //cout << c.aStruct.Ab; //works
    abstractFuncCheck(c);
    std::cin.get();
}
```

Now, the question/issue:
Using a `Circle` object, I can check `c`'s `aStruct` and `bStruct`, and all of its values are in place (the default ones [`Aa` & `Ba` --> defined in *Shape.h*], and the ones defined in the Circle constructor).

However, if I use the `abstractFuncCheck(Shape&)` function to check the values, only the default ones (defined in *Shape.h* --> `Aa` and `Ba`) are defined. The ones that should have been defined in the Circle constructor are showing up as undefined. This means that when I pass the `Circle` to the `abstractFuncCheck(Shape&)` function, it behaves as a `Shape`, and not a `Circle`.

Could anyone shed some light on this behavior? Or possibly give me an area of reading to look into?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Your compiler should have warned you about *shadowing*: every `Circle` object has two members `aStruct` and two members `bStruct`. One is inherited, one you have added manually in the `Circle` class.

Comment: Cannot believe I missed that. Thank you.
EDIT: My compiler did not warn me about this at all, using Visual Studio. I'll look into why I didn't get a warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Circle` class inherits `aStruct` and `bStruct` members from the `Shape` ancestor class, and then declares its own `aStruct` and `bStruct` members on top of that.  Thus `Circle` has 2 `aStruct` members and 2 `bStruct` members.  The `Circle` constructor is initializing only the `Circle` members, and the `Shape` members are default initialized.  When you then pass a `Circle` instance to `abstractFuncCheck()`, it knows how to access only the `Shape` members, which you have not initialized with your `Circle` values.

You need to remove the duplicate `Circle` members and let your `Circle` methods access the inherited `Shape` members when needed.

```
class Circle : public Shape {
private: //for some reason, names of variables MUST differ from the name of the function 
    int type1 = 0;
    int bonus1 = 1000;
public:
    Circle() {}
    Circle(int);

    int type() { return type1; }
    int bonus() { return bonus1; }

    //A aStruct; <-- remove this
    //B bStruct; <-- remove this
};
```

Comment: Wow, hah, thanks. For some reason I thought I was declaring (in the abstract class) that any subclasses MUST have those variables, like pure virtual functions.

Comment: **Data members** cannot be abstracted, they are concrete and belong to the class that declares them, and are accessible to derived classes if declared as `protected` or `public`.  Only **virtual methods** can be abstracted and overridden in derived classes.

Comment: Great reply, thank you. I'm still a little new to C++. I think I might switch the structs to `protected`, might fit my organization a little better.

Comment: @JhomasTefferson In C++, there's not a distinct concept for *abstract classes*. Any class with a pure virtual function is an *abstract class*.